# Crop video on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am getting `video` from the user's camera, and displaying it on a 1:1 square. I then have a button that takes a picture and draws it to a 1:1 canvas, the issue is that it isn't drawn in the same location on the canvas. How can I achieve this?

Here is a running example:

https://jsfiddle.net/90d3ar1m/

Here is the HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Camera</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src * 'unsafe-eval'; media-src 'self' blob:">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="camera">
            <video id="monitor" autoplay></video>
        </div>
        <canvas id="photo"></canvas>
        <input type=button value="&#x1F4F7;" onclick="snapshot()">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dist/pages/camera.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
video {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.camera {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the TypeScript:

```js
let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
let video: HTMLVideoElement;
$(window).on('load', async event => {
    video = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('monitor');
    canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('photo');

    video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        canvas.width = 500;
        canvas.height = 500;
    }

});

function snapshot() {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: have you tried absolutely positioning the elements on top of eachother?

Comment: That will just move the elements around, that won't affect where it is drawn on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be caused by the fact that the `video` element keeps the aspect ratio of the video, while the canvas does not. Also remember that ctx.drawImage takes up to eight positional and size arguments:

`context.drawImage(img/vid,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);`

I did some testing, and found this to work pretty well, but your mileage may vary:
`.drawImage(video,80,0,480,500,0,0,500,520);`

I made a [jsFiddle with these numbers](https://jsfiddle.net/90d3ar1m/5/), check it out to see if it works for you.

W3Schools has some great documentation on how these work, I suggest reading that:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

You could probably use the video's `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` attributes to calculate which numbers you need in `drawImage` for different aspect ratio source videos

Comment: I will be stretching the final result, to the width of the screen (this will run in Android Chrome upon completion). I am guessing that this will still work...

Comment: It should work, but you will need to tweak the numbers a bit, but you should be able to make that process automatic by using the width and height of both the container and the source video to calculate the numbers you need